# Java heap saw pattern

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I work with Java system which process data in batch mode. It's reading data from database, doing some calculation and writing results to another database.

I notice that Garbage Collector runs very often and clean a lot of heap space - for example from `800 MB` to `400 MB` (**50%**).

See screenshots below:

[image: JVisualVM screenshot after about 5 minutes]

[image: JVisualVM screenshot after about 10 minutes]

So I have two questions:

1. How to detect which objects are so short-lived? Maybe I can smooth memory usage.
2. Is such memory usage is fine or should alarm me that something wrong happens?

Comment: 1. Most of allocated objects are short-lived in your case. Use allocation profiler to find what is allocated. 2. Depends on the application. For a batch processing task this is usually not a problem at all. The graph shows GC activity takes only 0.3% CPU time - I guess there is nothing to optimize here.

Comment: Ok. GC don't use CPU, but maybe memory allocation (object creation) slows down application? Is it possible?

Comment: When it doesn’t take CPU time, it doesn’t slow down. According to the graph, your application uses only 20% of the CPU anyway. So you’re running on a single core out of four? If you want to increase the speed, think about *that*. But if it didn’t occur to you, why do you think you have a problem? But perhaps, you’re using only 20% of the CPU, because your application is I/O bound, so you’re looking at the wrong end anyway…

Comment: @Holger Sorry I didn't mention that screenshot shows only one of four processes running on one server. There are another fifth process which wait during calculation and some other applications. So 20% of CPU is justified.
I will search for a allocation profiler tool and try to find what's happen behind the scene.

Comment: You may do that, but consider what apangin said. Your GC related CPU consumption wiggles around 1% and that’s the maximum performance gain you could get by optimizing allocations. Is that worth the effort? The “used heap” graph on the right is just numbers. You could make the curve smoother by just setting a tighter limit on the maximum heap size, but besides a nice looking graph, it wouldn’t be an improvement, actually, it would slow down the application.

Comment: If your concern is performance then measure where CPU cycles are spent instead of guessing that there might be a performance issue based on some GC charts.